# Unix Domain Socket Error Codes?

Tags: mysql, solaris, unix-socket

I've been occasionally [reviewing an unsolved mystery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46180/what-makes-this-rare-error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket) on a Solaris 10 setup we have been running, and I noticed something in the error message that might yield a clue to help me solve the mystery.

The error message is when connecting to MySQL on a UNIX Domain Socket.

I have a specific question here, which is about [the error code at the end](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46180/what-makes-this-rare-error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket#comment97991_46184).

See these three error messages:

- `mysql -S /tmp/missing.sock` outputs
  `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/missing.sock' (2)`
- `mysql -S /dev/null` outputs
  `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/dev/null' (95)`
- The rare and intermittent error I am trying to resolve is
  `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (146)`

That number at the end: Is this a UNIX Domain Socket error code? If so, is there a place I can look up the meaning of that code?

As I said, this is a specific question. Other helpful input should be posted to [the other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46180/what-makes-this-rare-error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket).

Comment: Those error codes come from MySQL.

Comment: The numbers in parentheses are almost certainly system error numbers, normally reported via `errno`, found via `#include <errno.h>` though the numbers are usually (on Solaris) in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` (but can be in other places, especially on Linux and Mac OS X).  You could write a program `#include <stdio.h> #include <string.h> int main(void) { puts(strerror(2)); puts(strerror(95)); puts(strerror(146)); return 0; }` to see the 3 errors. 2 is probably ENOENT, no such file or directory; 95 may be ENOTSOCK (not a socket); 146 might be ENOTSUPP (operation not supported).

Comment: @Marcell, Based on Jonathan's answer, your comment is not entirely correct. The codes come **through** MySQL, seemingly **from** Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in parentheses are almost certainly system error numbers, normally reported via `errno`, the definitions for which are found via `#include <errno.h>` though on Solaris the numbers are usually in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h` (but can be in other places, especially on Linux and Mac OS X).  You could write a simple program to see the 3 errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts(strerror(2));
    puts(strerror(95));
    puts(strerror(146));
    return 0;
}
```

*Conjecture*:
2 is probably ENOENT, no such file or directory; 95 may be ENOTSOCK (not a socket); 146 might be ENOTSUPP (operation not supported).

[George Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463304/george-bailey) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427264/unix-domain-socket-error-codes/20427926#comment30512516_20427926):

> On my system, the answer was in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h`:
>
> - 2=ENOENT
> - 95=ENOTSOCK
> - 146=ECONNREFUSED

Note that error numbers up to the mid-twenties tend to be consistent across systems as the error codes existed in 7th Edition Unix.  Higher numbers diverge. For example, on Mac OS X 10.9:

- 2 (ENOENT): No such file or directory
- 95 (EMULTIHOP): Reserved
- errno: no message for errno = 146
- ENOTSOCK (38): Socket operation on non-socket
- ECONNREFUSED (61): Connection refused

On SuSE (SLES 10 SP2 — antique, but these numbers don't change much):

- 2 (ENOENT): No such file or directory
- 95 (EOPNOTSUPP): Operation not supported on transport endpoint
- errno: no message for errno = 146
- ENOTSOCK (88): Socket operation on non-socket
- ECONNREFUSED (111): Connection refused

These answers were obtained via a program `errno` that reports on error numbers and names. It has to be compiled for each different system.

---

Note that there is a consistent MySQL-provided component to the messages:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/dev/null' (95)
```

roughly as if the format string for the `printf()` statement was:

```
"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '%s' (%s)\n"
```

The name of the 'socket' file is being provided — very helpful — and (educated guess) the system error number, collected at some point from `errno`. However, `errno` is volatile — almost any library function may set it to a non-zero value — so you need to preserve a specific value (copy it) before doing much in the way of error reporting work, such as reading message files to get the correct translation of the format string.

Comment: Thanks! On my system, the answer was in `/usr/include/sys/errno.h`. 2=`ENOENT`, 95=`ENOTSOCK`, 146=`ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: The 'is probably', 'may be' and 'might be' were graduated scales of confidence. I don't have access to a Solaris machine any more, so I couldn't check.

Comment: I understand, I just posted my results in case it is useful to others.